# h2 allow at time zone 'utc' functionality

Tags: sql, h2

i  use postgres for my database, and h2 for unit testing my java code.  i have a query which uses the syntax "current_timestamp at time zone 'utc'" but h2 doesn't seem to support that syntax.  how can i use this type of feature with using h2 database?